# Equally separating words in Python

Tags: python, string, list, listbox, format

What I want to do is separate chunks of text so that I have two chunks in each line and in the different lines they begin at the same point. What I am using it for is a little book manager program I am developing for my own usage, so it should look something like this:

```
Book Title Here                    Author Name Here
Little longer title here           Author Name Here
shorter here                       Author Name Here
```

I tried making use of `.ljust()` or `.rjust()` using spaces, but it didn't really work for me: for whatever reason, the spaces would not even out and I ended up not having the titles stacked up together, but rather separated by very little.

I am using Tkinter to build the GUI, and each line should be an item on a list box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using the [format mini-language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), here's the setup:

```
bookdict = {
  'Little longer title here': 'Author Name Here',
  'Book Title Here': 'Another Author Name Here',
  'shorter here': 'Diff Name Here'}
bookwidth = max(map(len, bookdict.keys()))
authorwidth = max(map(len, bookdict.values()))
```

#### `format` mini-language

And this usage of the mini-language:

```
template = '{{0:<{bw}}} {{1:>{aw}}}'.format(bw=bookwidth, aw=authorwidth)
for book, author in bookdict.items():
    print( template.format(book, author) )
```

prints:

```
Little longer title here         Author Name Here
Book Title Here          Another Author Name Here
shorter here                       Diff Name Here
```

To break that down, the doubled braces will be preserved on the first format and reduced to single braces, and the single braces will become the width of the max lens calculated, e.g.:

```
'{0:<30} {1:>20}'
```

The less-than (`<`) means justify left, and the greater-than (`>`) means justify right.

#### `rjust` and `ljust`

If you really want to use the str.rjust and str.ljust methods:

```
for book, author in bookdict.items():
    print(book.ljust(bookwidth) + ' ' + author.rjust(authorwidth))
```

prints:

```
Little longer title here         Author Name Here
shorter here                       Diff Name Here
Book Title Here          Another Author Name Here
```

Comment: I tried it out and it works all right when I print it, but when I plug it into the list box, it doesn't I don't really know why, I'm guessing it has something to do with the font tkinter uses as default

Comment: It was indeed, as I changed the font your solution worked well for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a fixed-width font, then `"{:40}{}".format("Book Title Here", "Author Name Here"` is your friend. (Change 40 to however many spaces you want to allocate for the first part.)

If you are using a variable-width font, then you'll want to do this using Tkinter's ways of arranging things, which would likely boil down to putting the two parts of each line in their own sections.

For instance, you could do something along the lines of:

```
Label(master, text="Book Title Here").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
Label(master, text="Author Name Here").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

Label(master, text="Little longer title here").grid(row=1, sticky=W)
Label(master, text="Author Name Here").grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
```